# C# Regex to match whole brackets contents

Tags: regex

I need help fixing the regular expression below. I tried to rewrite it from Python to C#, but C# displays empty m.value. Thanks!

In Python it works well and displays brackets and inside contents:

Python Code:

```
r1="(dog apple text) (grape cushion cat)"
a=re.findall("[(]+[/s]+[a-z]+[)]+",r1)
print(a[:]) 
//Conent gives me (dog apple text) (grape cushion cat) , so if I will call print(a[0]) it will give me (dog apple text)

 String r1="(dog apple text) (grape cushion cat)"
    String pat=@"[(]+[/s]+[a-z]+[)]+";

      foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(irregv, pat2))
                {                  
                    Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", m.Value);                             
                }
```

Comment: `/s` should be `\s` but even then your expression would match things like `((((((       hello))` rather than anything in your example. You'd be best off starting out with some tutorials - http://regular-expressions.info has a lot of good info with examples. Also worth checking out [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex doesn't work in python either.

You want to use:

```
\([a-z\s]+\)
```

`\(` matches one opening bracket, `[a-z\s]` allows letters (lowercase) and any sort of whitespaces through `\s` (notice the *anti*-slash).

See (and play with) [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/eV5lM7).